# How would you deploy an ionic frameworks app on the iTunes store?

Tags: deployment, ionic-framework, hybrid-mobile-app, itunes-store

I know I'll probably get told "let me google that for you", but I am struggling to find any information on how I should go about deploying a hybrid app built with Ionic Framework via iTunes.

Could anybody point me towards some tutorials or resources?

The ionic framework forums appear to be down so I can't look there.

Comment: let me google that for you : http://gonehybrid.com/build-your-first-mobile-app-with-the-ionic-framework-part-6/

Comment: I had looked at this page already not well enough it seems as I didn't see the final paragraph. When I saw the title I though it mean just deploying for testing. Thanks for your help. I will probably delete my questions as it isn't a very technical one.

Answer (score 0):

You need to have Xcode installed on your mac. From within your project do `ionic platform add ios` and then `ionic build ios`. Navigate to `myApp/platforms/ios/myApp.xcodeproj`. This is your ios Xcode project. You can open this up in Xcode and follow normal process from there.